# Opencart product and banner images are not coming after server change

Tags: image, opencart

I built a opencart based website in my local server and last night i moved my local files to  one free hosting. Now the product and banner images are not coming properly. In chrome i went to console it's showing below errors.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/undefined    
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/undefined
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/undefined
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/undefined
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/undefined
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/undefined
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/undefined
```

I cant able to upload images in backed with file manager too. If i upload any image it's simply loading for long time.

My site is http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/

My root config file is,

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/admin/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/u230336461/public_html/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/u230336461/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/u230336461/public_html/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/u230336461/public_html/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/u230336461/public_html/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/u230336461/public_html/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'home/u230336461/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/u230336461/public_html/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/u230336461/public_html/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/u230336461/public_html/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'mysql.1freehosting.com');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'u230336461_homeg');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'u230336461_homegym');
define('DB_PREFIX', '');
?>
```

And my admin config file is,

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/image/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://magichomegym.hostingsiteforfree.com/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/u230336461/public_html/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/u230336461/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/u230336461/public_html/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/u230336461/public_html/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/u230336461/public_html/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/u230336461/public_html/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/u230336461/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/u230336461/public_html/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/u230336461/public_html/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/u230336461/public_html/system/logs/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/u230336461/public_html/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'mysql.1freehosting.com');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'u230336461_homeg');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'u230336461_homegym');
define('DB_PREFIX', '');
?>
```

Did anyone knows any idea about this?

Comment: can you post your config.php file? have you made the required changes there

Comment: thanks for your quick reply zdesam. I added my config files above. Please check it. I hope i added those correctly.